# bash setting generated variables

Tags: bash, variables, set

I have a variable name that is made up of the string orig_endpoints_ with the name of a file (sans extension).
I can view this using eval echo like so:

```
[bash]# PCAP_FILE=test_w_three.pcap
[bash]# orig_endpoints_test_w_three=blah
[bash]# eval echo "\$$(echo orig_endpoints_${PCAP_FILE%.*})"
blah
[bash]#
```

Now how do I set this variable to a space separated list of src ips:dst ips? I tried eval set and don't seem to be having any luck.

```
[bash]# orig_endpoints_test_w_three=
[bash]# tmpOrig="10.21.20.66:10.21.20.57 10.21.20.66:10.21.22.25 10.21.20.66:10.21.22.51 10.21.20.66:10.65.111.219     10.21.20.66:10.65.111.220 10.21.20.66:10.65.111.30 10.21.20.66:10.65.52.48"
[bash]# eval set orig_endpoints_${PCAP_FILE%.*}=$tmpOrig
[bash]# eval echo \$$(echo orig_endpoints_${PCAP_FILE%.*})

[bash]# echo $orig_endpoints_test_w_three

[bash]#
```

Would anybody know how I can set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
eval orig_endpoints_${PCAP_FILE%.*}='$tmpOrig'
```

Quoting is important, the `set` is unnecessary here AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `declare`:

```
declare orig_endpoints_${PCAP_FILE%.*}=$tmpOrig
```

Comment: are there advantages of using declare over eval?